# To remove Unicode character from String in Java using REGEX

Tags: java, regex, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I am having Input String like below.

```
String comment = "Good morning! \u2028\u2028I am looking to purchase a new Honda car as I\u2019m outgrowing my current car. I currently drive a Hyundai Accent and I was looking for something a
 little bit larger and more comfortable like the Honda Civic. May I know if you have any of the models currently in stock? Thank you! Warm regards Sandra";
```

I want to remove Unicode characters like "\u2028" , "\u2019" etc if it is present in the comment section.In runtime i don't know what are all extra characters coming. So what is the best way to handle this?

I tried like below which removes unicode characters in the given string.

```
Comments.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
```

So what is the best way to  match Unicode characters are present in the comment section and if present remove those, otherwise just pass the comment to target system.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Not sure why you want to remove single quotes (`\u2019`). These are normal chars. What do you want to get in the end, as a result?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew,
I am facing issue after pushing those values (without removal of Unicode characters) into Salesforce.that's why tried to remove. Bishan mentioned in below answer , lost some characters. so yet to test his answer ...let me know if u need any further details.

Comment: I have a suggestion: what if you remove only symbols, punctuation and whitespace that is not ASCII? Try `.replaceAll("[\\p{Z}\\p{P}\\p{S}&&[^\\p{ASCII}]]", "")`. Or, if you want to "normalize" all Unicode whitespace to a single regular space, and remove Unicode punctuation/symbols, try `comment.replaceAll("(?U)\\s+", " ").replaceAll("[\\p{P}\\p{S}&&[^\\p{ASCII}]]", "")`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew,
Thanks for ur suggestion,It works fine.but instead of replace Unicode punctuation/symbols as empty, is there any way to get exact characters. like( \u2019 )becomes ( ' ). can we replace 
all characters during runtime?"normalize" all Unicode whitespace to a single regular space is fine.

Comment: There is such a thing in Python. I have just googled Java's port, not sure it is working, see https://github.com/xuender/unidecode

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew,
Thanks for again, reviewed it but unfortunately i can't able to find the required thing in the class called Unidecode in above github repo.can u tell me which portion is suitable for my case in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this sequentially like below:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    String comment = "Good morning! \u2028\u2028I am looking to purchase a new Honda car as I\u2019m outgrowing my current car. I currently drive a Hyundai Accent and I was looking for something a little bit larger and more comfortable like the Honda Civic. May I know if you have any of the models currently in stock? Thank you! Warm regards Sandra";

    // remove all non-ASCII characters
    comment = comment.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");

    // remove all the ASCII control characters
    comment = comment.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]", "");

    // removes non-printable characters from Unicode
    comment = comment.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
    System.out.println(comment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `replace`, you will lost some characters, For example `I'm` will become `Im`. So the best thing is convert.

You can Convert Unicode to UTF-8.

```
byte[] byteComment = comment.getBytes("UTF-8");

String formattedComment = new String(byteComment, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi @Bishan,
Thanks for ur suggestion, "\u2028" this will become "?" when i tried to convert to UTF-8.but in this place (I'm) working.let me know if u have any concern